# mediastreamsegmenter on a public dropbox link not working

Tags: media, http-live-streaming, dropbox-api, mediastreamsource, mediastreamsegmenter

I have a streamable url from my dropbox **public** link: 
        https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/1/view/taf4hn5q1lbppmx/Public/01Track1.mp3

I would like to stream this to my ios device so I read upon HTTP Live Streaming doc from Apple.

So, i am trying to use the mediastreamsegmenter to get the index file in .m3u8 format.

```
 mediastreamsegmenter -f ./test/  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/1/view/taf4hn5q1lbppmx/Public/01Track1.mp3
```

The above gave me an invalid port error and so i listed :8080 and tried but it still does not work.

Does mediastreamsegmenter work on https/TCP? or only with UDP? Where am i going wrong here?